# How to create HTTP end-point which accepts POST data in Salesforce

Tags: apex, httppost

I need to create a HTTP end-point for receiving transaction notifications from a payment gateway.

How would I create a HTTP end-point which accepts POST requests with a variable set of parameters.

**POST Request Body**

```
txndate_processed=26%2F06%2F18+18%3A10%3A36
&ccbin=403587
&timezone=Europe%2FLondon
&oid=C-8080f191-df6f-41f6-99a0-b5f926cbcf8a
&cccountry=DEU
&expmonth=12
&hash_algorithm=SHA256
&endpointTransactionId=0005
&currency=826
&processor_response_code=00
&chargetotal=799.00
&terminal_id=21400840
&approval_code=XXXXXXX
&expyear=2048
&response_code_3dsecure=1
&notification_hash=XXXXXXXXXXX
&transactionNotificationURL=http%3A%2F%2F.example.com
&tdate=1530029436
&installments_interest=false
&bname=Mr+Smith
&ccbrand=VISA
&refnumber=866834
&txntype=sale
&paymentMethod=V
&txndatetime=2018%3A06%3A26-16%3A10%3A14
&cardnumber=%28VISA%29+...+4977
&ipgTransactionId=84516494556
&status=APPROVED
```

I don't think I can use a REST end-point, because the request body is not JSON or XML.

Comment: Check out this old developer forum thread about using a [site page as a post handler](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000099s9IAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still set up an `ApexRest` endpoint. There's nothing magic about it that requires JSON nor XML.

You can whip up a simple demo to prove `ApexRest` is sufficient for your needs:

```
@RestResource(UrlMapping='/Demo/*')
global class Demo
{
    @HttpPost
    global static void doStuff()
    {
        String body = RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();
        Map<String, String> params = new Map<String, String>();
        for (String param : body.split('&'))
        {
            if (param.contains('='))
            {
                params.put(param.substringBefore('=').trim(), param.substringAfter('=').trim());
            }
        }
        system.debug(JSON.serialize(params));
    }
}
```

Then post your payload to that endpoint. I used workbench and got exactly the expected results.